# vuejs using v-model dynamically

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've got basic select that I want bind to empty array. I use vuetify, but this problem is universal.

```
<v-select
v-model="items.physicianSpeciality"
>
</v-select>
```

now I want to use the same select to many arrays, depend on offer.person value that could be physician, nurse etc.

```
data: {
offer.person: "physician" //or offer.person: "nurse"
}
```

For example for physician I want to use v-model `items.physicianSpeciality` For nurse I want to use v-model `items.nurseSpeciality`, etc.

I tried to make something like:

```
<v-select
v-model="this['items.' + offer.person + 'Speciality']"
>
</v-select>
```

but this gives me an error:

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "items.physicianSpeciality" 
is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. 
Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, 
or for class-based components, by initializing the property.
```

while this works:

```
<v-select
v-model="items.physicianSpeciality"
>
</v-select>
```

What is wrong here? How should correct my code to make this work?

Comment: why not remove the `this` in `this['items.' + offer.person + 'Speciality']`

Comment: @xianshenglu this gives `[WDS] Errors while compiling. Reload prevented.`

Comment: try `v-model="items[offer.person + 'Speciality']"` or  `v-model="items[this.offer.person + 'Speciality']"`?

Comment: wait,how could use like `data: {
offer.person: "physician" 
}`,get no error?`offer.person` as key?

Comment: @xianshenglu this seems working, but I've got some errors, I need to check them

Comment: @xianshenglu `v-model="items[offer.person + 'Speciality']"` works, thank you for help! `data: { offer.person: "physician" }` is wrong, but just to show data variable in this question

Comment: ok,i put it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
v-model="this['items.' + offer.person + 'Speciality']"
```

to

```
v-model="items[offer.person + 'Speciality']"
```